# How to access **kwargs in Pydantic's validator method

Tags: python, pydantic

I wanted to validate the below stated payload -

```
payload = {
    "emailId":['jeet@steinnlabs.com', 'jeet@dope.security'],
    "role":"Administrator",
}
```

Hence, I created a class using Pydantic's `BaseModel` like this -

```
class SendInvitePayloadValidator(BaseModel):

    emailId: List[str]
    role: str

    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid

    @validator('emailId')
    def validate_email(cls, emailID):
        pass
```

Now, I also wanted to validate each key of payload e.g `emailId` but in order to do that I need another an extra value lets say `tenantId`.

If I include `tenantId` in the model then the payload validation won't work.

So is there a way I could just pass few extra values to the validator method?

Comment: Where do you get `tenantId` ?

Comment: I get from the access token.

Comment: I would suggest you validate the data associated with external data before saving the data to the model.